# crear ejecutable de una aplicacion en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Si me pudieran colaborar en indicarme algún tutorial, para poder crear un archivo .exe de mi aplicación en python, el cual contiene una pantalla realizada con QT Designer (archivo .ui), el cual cargo en mi archivo .py, pero ya he visto varios tutoriales que dice que debo convertir el archivo .ui a .py, pero luego me presenta problema para cargarlo en mi código py, si existe alguna posibilidad de generar el archivo .exe cargando el archivo .ui y me pueden indicar como se lo agradecería.

Parte del código donde invoco al archivo .ui :

```
class Dialogo(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("ventana.ui",self)
        self.setWindowTitle('File Processing Tool')
        self.Button_output.clicked.connect(self.Asignacion_out)
        self.Button_invoice.clicked.connect(self.Asignacion_invoice)
        self.Button_certificado.clicked.connect(self.Asignacion_certificado)
        self.Button_validar.clicked.connect(self.validar)
        self.Button_cerrar.clicked.connect(self.closeEvent)
        self.Button_output_path.clicked.connect(self.Asignacion_path)
```

Comment: una forma mas facil para crear ejecutables es con [auto-py-to-exe](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe) que probe una gui con la cual puedes crear ejecutables de forma mucho mas facil. [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO3TG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO3TG.png)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes crear un ejecutable con *Pyinstaller*.

En primer lugar asegúrate de que el directorio de instalación de *Python*, así como el subdirectorio *Scripts*, se encuentren en el *path* del sistema.

A continuación, para instalar *Pyinstaller* ejecuta en la consola de comandos:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Navega al directorio en el que se encuentra tu programa desde la consola de comandos y ejecuta:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data "ventana.ui;." programa.py
```

El argumento `--onefile` se encarga de que tu programa sea un único ejecutable, y los archivos de los que depende tu programa serán descomprimidos en un directorio temporal en cada ejecución.

Para que tu programa pueda encontrar el archivo `ventana.ui` **previamente deberías haber definido esta función**:

```
import sys, os

def resource_path(relative_path):

    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path) # Para programa.exe

    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path) # Para programa.py
```

`sys._MEIPASS` es una variable que utiliza *Pyinstaller*, determina cual es el directorio temporal empleado durante la ejecución del programa (el cual cambia en cada ejecución). La función `resource_path` devuelve el *path* de tu archivo *.ui* pasado como argumento tanto si el programa se está ejecutando como *.py* como si se está ejecutando como *.exe*.

Para cargar el archivo *.ui* utiliza la función `resource_path` que acabamos de definir:

```
uic.loadUi(resource_path("ventana.ui"), self)
```

**NOTA 1:** Si por algún motivo no te funciona el empaquetamiento con los argumentos `--onefile` o `--windowed` puedes omitirlos. En este caso se creará un directorio que contiene el programa (pero sin ser un *standalone*, y no es necesaria la función `resource_path`), y puedes emplear la utilidad **Bat2Exe Converter** para crear el *standalone* a partir de este directorio, así como para ocultar la consola de comandos.

**NOTA 2:** Como alternativa a la función `resource_path`, al inicio de tu *script* lo siguiente debería funcionar (aunque no lo he comprobado):

```
import sys, os

if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)
```