# ¿Cómo compilar una GUI compuesta por diversos módulos?

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica, pyinstaller

***¡Hola Comunidad!***

He creado una aplicación sencilla en la que todos los módulos se encuentran ubicados en un mismo directorio. Dentro de él, habrán subdirectorios para alojar diversos archivos (imágenes y archivos con extensión .py).

El nombre del directorio del proyecto es *Directorio_App* y su jerarquía puede apreciarse en el siguiente archivo adjunto:

[image: Jerarquía del directorio del proyecto]

El código de cada módulo se muestra a continuación:

**`app.py`:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import frame_app as fm_app

class App:
    '''
    Clase principal de la GUI de prueba
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        frame = fm_app.FrameApp(self.root)
        
    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemmplo = App()
    ejemmplo.mainloop()
```

**`frame_app.py`:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import pathlib
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

from modules import modulo_sumar as mod_sum

class FrameApp(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        i_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).absolute().parent / 'images/una_imagen.png'
        i_load = Image.open(i_path)
        i_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i_load)

        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        tk.Label(self, text='Esta es una GUI de prueba'
            ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')

        imagen_en_label = tk.Label(self, image=i_image)
        imagen_en_label.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
        imagen_en_label.img_ref = i_image

        tk.Label(self, text='La suma de 2+2 es:', bg='yellow').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')

        suma = mod_sum.Sumar(2,2)

        tk.Label(self, text=suma.resultado, bg='yellow').grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w')
```

**`modulo_sumar.py`:**

```
import numpy as np

class Sumar:
    '''
    Módulo que realiza la suma de dos valores utilizando
    la biblioteca NumPy.
    '''
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):

        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

        self.resultado = np.add(self.num1, self.num2)
```

**Observaciones:**

- Se ignora en esta publicación el contenido de los archivos AUTORES.txt, DEPENDENCIAS.txt, LÉEME.txt y LICENCIA.txt ya que no son relevantes para la problemática relacionada a la pregunta.
- En el subdiretorio "*images*" se encuentra una imagen en formato .PNG que será utilizada en el archivo `frame_app.py`.Imaginemos que dentro de este subdirectorio pueden encontrarse muchas imágenes más.
- El módulo `modulo_sumar.py`contiene instrucciones para realizar una suma entre dos valores implementando la librería NumPy. Estas instrucciones serán importadas en el archivo `frame_app.py`.Imaginemos que dentro de este subdirectorio pueden encontrarse muchos otros módulos (y más complejos claro está).

Una vez que ya ha finalizado el periodo de desarrollo de la aplicación es común generar un archivo distribuible, en mi caso un archivo .EXE, ya que la aplicación está diseñada para correr bajo el sistema operativo Windows. El objetivo de generar este archivo es que pueda ser ejecutado en cualquier ordenador bajo ese sistema, sin importar que tenga o no instalado Python.

Para ello, instalé la libreria `pyinstaller`, la cual será la encargada de generar el archivo .EXE

Ubicándome en el directorio *"Directorio_App"* en la CMD las instrucciones que escribí para crearlo fueron:

```
C:\Users\gv_pro\Desktop\Directorio_App>pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --icon=./logo.ico app.py
```

Luego me dirigí hasta la carpeta que se crea dentro de *Directorio_App* luego de la anterior instrucción llamada *dist* y, efectivamente se consigue crear el archivo `app.exe`, **pero al intentar ejecutarlo se muestra el siguiente error:**

[image: Error que muestra Windows]

**¿Qué ha salido mal?**

Debo acotar que probé la app antes de intentar compilarla y funcionaba sin problemas.

***¡Gracias por sus comentarios y/o sugerencias!***

Comment: Puedes intentar quitar el `--windowed` y reemplazar tu archivo `app.py` a `app.pyw`, sigue sin funcionar? Adicionalmente, si puedes pega el archivo `app.spec` que genera el pyinstaller

Comment: ah y se me acaba de ocurrir que jalas `images/una_imagen.png`. Pyinstaller por default no te va a jalar la carpeta `images`, intenta copiarla a la carpeta donde está el exe generado

Comment: En [crear ejecutable de una aplicacion en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320334/crear-ejecutable-de-una-aplicacion-en-python/320400#320400) tienes la respuesta sobre cómo añadir recursos a un ejecutable creado con *pyinstaller* con el *flag --onefile*. El problema es que un *standlaone* creado con *pyinstaller* descomprime los recursos en un directorio temporal.